# Integration of the curve

Tags: calculus

Question: $$\int_0^∞\int_0^x ye^{-xy}~dy~dx$$

Using change of order of integration I got :

$$\int_0^x\int_0^∞ ye^{-xy}~dx~dy$$

This is giving me integral to be $-x$ whereas answer is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your change of order is not correct. The limits in the outer integral have to be constant. You should draw a picture of the region to correctly change the order of integration (it is not just swapping the integrals).

Comment: Your region is a sector of the plane. You should find the limits for $y$ on that sector and then set the limits for $x$ for each fixed $y$.

Comment: 0<y<x and 0<x<∞ so doesn't  my limits fall for this

Comment: Wait is : $$int_0^∞ \int_0^y ye^{-xy}~dx~dy $$correct?

Comment: No, it is not. It must be $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\int\limits_y^{\infty}(...)dxdy$.

Comment: How did u get the limits of x

Comment: Just draw your region: $x\ge0$ and $0\le y\le x$. It is an "angle" between the positive $x$-axis and the bisector $y=x$. On this angle, $y$ takes all positive values, $y\in[0,\infty)$ while, for fixed $y$, $x$ varies between $x$ and $+\infty$ (draw horizontal lines, corresponding to fixed $y$, and check your entry and exit points.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense but it should be x>0 snd 0<y<x or am I wrong?

Comment: No, it should be $x\ge y$ because your region is under the bisector $y=x$ ($y\le x$). If you fix $y$, the points in your region have $x\ge y$ and the limits are $\int_y^\infty\cdots$